# TypeError: sql() missing 1 required positional argument: 'sqlQuery' in pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I'm trying to estimate proportion of maths marks in pyspark 3.0.1 on data bricks. Some of the cases my total_marks are 0.So I wrote following code

```
 df_data.registerTempTable('myTable')
 df_oversees2=SQLContext.sql("select A.*,case when total_marks=0 then 0 else (maths_marks/total_marks) end as prop_maths from myTable A ")
```

But I'm getting error message

```
TypeError: sql() missing 1 required positional argument: 'sqlQuery'
```

Can you please help me to resolve the issue?
I also verified that my total_marks & maths_marks are present in my table using below code

```
df1 = sqlContext.sql("select maths_marks,total_marks from myTable")
df1.show()
```

I'm seeing the output for both the fields

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`SQLContext` is different from `sqlContext` - the latter is an `SQLContext` attached to a `SparkContext`, while the former is a class not attached to any `SparkContext`. Therefore, you need to do:

```
sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)
df_oversees2 = sqlContext.sql("your query")
```

In any case, it is deprecated and the better way would be to call

```
spark.sql("your query")
```

where `spark` is a `sparkSession` object.

Comment: I'm getting `parse exception ` with spark.sql

Comment: I have resolved the issue. By mistake there was a "#" given. Removed that & now it's running